# How to split a string column and then take a join? if any of the split value match, join is successful - Snowflake

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, inner-join

In Snowflake I have 2 tables, Candidate and Employee. I want to split column CandidateName by spaces and then take a join with Employee on column EmployeeName. For example, if I split `Ali - Hasan Khan` then it will give me 4 values: `Ali`, `-`, `Hasan`, `Khan`. If any of these 4 values are in column EmployeeName then the join will be successful.

Candidate:

| CandidateId | CandidateName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Muhammad Bilal |
| 2 | Ali - Hasan Khan |
| 3 | Tehseen Nawaz |

Employee:

| EmployeeName | StartDate |
| --- | --- |
| Muhammad Bilal | 2022-02-15 |
| Ali Hasan | 2022-03-17 |
| Tehseen Nawaz Virk | 2022-01-10 |

Desired result:

| CandidateName | StartDate |
| --- | --- |
| Muhammad Bilal | 2022-02-15 |
| Ali - Hasan Khan | 2022-03-17 |
| Tehseen Nawaz | 2022-01-10 |

Comment: I think you may want to revisit that logic - if any of the split elements match is considered a success, you're likely going to get a ton of false positive matches where first names and surnames are not unique (as well as hyphens).

Comment: It will work, I am doing this on 2 columns which will be 100% unique. So logic will work. :) Thanks for the response

Comment: Your premise states "If any of these 4 values join/contain in EmployeeName column then join will be successful".  All you need are 2 different records where the name is hyphenated where this wouldn't work, much less common names.  If you're now saying you plan to use 2 values as a minimum for matching is the rule, that will help but still not eliminate possible false positives prospectively (unless these tables contain static data that will never change).

Comment: Hey Jim, I am taking 4 to 5 joins which are very strict, this is a 6th join which is not strict. So most of the scenarios will be covered with previous joins and the remaining ones will be covered with this join. :). Can you guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you post your code and process in more detail - you're disclosing critical elements of your approach with each comment that readers here would find valuable in assisting you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ARRAY_INTERSECTION for this:

```
create table candidate (CandidateId number,     CandidateName varchar )
as select * from values 
(1, 'Muhammad Bilal'),
(2, 'Ali - Hasan Khan'),
(3, 'Tehseen Nawaz');

create table employee 
( EmployeeName  varchar, StartDate date) as select * from values
('Muhammad Bilal',  '2022-02-15'),
('Ali Hasan','2022-03-17'),
('Tehseen Nawaz Virk',  '2022-01-10');

select c.CandidateName, e.StartDate
from candidate c
join employee e on ARRAY_INTERSECTION( split(e.employeename,' '), split(c.candidatename,' ')) <> [];

+------------------+------------+
|  CANDIDATENAME   | STARTDATE  |
+------------------+------------+
| Muhammad Bilal   | 2022-02-15 |
| Ali - Hasan Khan | 2022-03-17 |
| Tehseen Nawaz    | 2022-01-10 |
+------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi Gokhan, thanks for the response. Let me try It and I will come back to you.

Comment: Interesting - how would this query change if you wanted to have a minimum of 2 items in the array match?

Comment: @JimDemitriou you can use array_size on intersection: join employee e on ARRAY_SIZE( ARRAY_INTERSECTION( split(e.employeename,' '), split(c.candidatename,' '))) >= 2;